# phpMyAdmin gives export.php instead of database sql dump

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

**Environment**

- Wamp server 2.5 x64 (MySQL 5.6.17, phpmyadmin4.1.14) on Windows 10 Enterprise x64 (Fresh installation, no major changes since yesterday total installation)
- Full control access to `C:\wamp\tmp\` folder for windows `everyone` group, and the folder is not read-only

**Problem**

When I try to export my database using `Export` tab, under my database page, It gives me the `export.php` file, the `body` part of which is like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>phpMyAdmin - Error</h1>
    <p>export.php: Missing parameter: export_type&lt;a href="./doc/html/faq.html#faqmissingparameters" target="documentation"&gt;&lt;img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;<br /></p>
</body>
```

But, I expect the `.sql` dump file!

**My effort**

- I googled for `export.php: Missing parameter: export_type` with no success.
- I also visited `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/doc/html/faq.html#faqmissingparameters` for any useful notes, with no success.
- In `config.inc.php`, the `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']` directive is empty.
- In `php.ini` the `arg_separator.input` directive has value `;&`.

**Edit**

Screenshot added, right before pressing `Go` button

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I tried to use my browser's (Google Chrome 47.0.x.x) console to see If there is something wrong with it and I noticed this warning there:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/x-sql

Then I tried disable my browser's extensions one-by-one where I found this extension was the cause:

```
Free Download Manager Chrome extension (1.0.23)
```

I disabled it and now everything is fine.

Comment: You saved my day, well the rest of my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue on a CentOS Cloud Server with Magento CE installed. My selection was to Export all tables, SQL format, Save to Output File, Add "Drop Table..", Add "IF NOT EXISTS".
Instead of dropping a .sql file, it always dropped a "sql" file without any extension and regardless any filename I was choosing. Inside that "sql" file there was the html source of the current phpmyadmin page!
I solved the issue by uncommenting and increasing the variable "max_input_vars" inside php.ini to 3000 rather than 1000.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to export my Magento database. And phpmyadmin instead of dropping a .sql file, retured a sql named file with no extension. Finally, I solved the problem by navigating to the php.ini file and uncommenting the "**max_input_vars**" variable and increasing its value. Don't forget to **restart** your xampp/wamp server after making the changes in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check up "Settings"(from main menu),then "Export" tab. "Save as file" checkbox should be checked.
2. When you setting up the export options, choose:

   - "Custom - display all possible options" radio button instead "Quick".
   - Set "Save output to file" radiobutton in "Output" section.
   - Set "Format" dropdown box to "SQL".

Then  press "Go" button.

Comment: All setting are like you have mentioned above. Nothing left for me to change!

Comment: If you don't mind using command prompt:  
     
c:\>mysqldump -u you_db_user_name -p your_db_name >c:\file_name.sql

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are running **http://localhost/phpmyadmin/export.php** on Google Chrome. Switch to some other browser (Ex: Microsoft Edge) and then run **http://localhost/phpmyadmin/export.php**. Now export the database as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, but I solved it after increasing the `Disk Space Usage` of website.
I don't know your probblem will be solved or not but i solve by increasing `Disk Space Usage`

Answer (score 0):

Hi select custom display option when exporting database and uncheck option

```
Dump TIMESTAMP columns in UTC (enables TIMESTAMP columns to be dumped and reloaded between servers in different time zones)
```

This will resolve the issue.